# Cannot read property of undefined - filter Jquery

Tags: jquery, angularjs, filter, properties, undefined

```
function ($scope, $stateParams, $http, WineService, $rootScope) {

var wineList = [];
getAllWineIDsOfEvent();
setAttributesOfWine();

function getAllWineIDsOfEvent() {
    var wineIDofEvent = $($scope.tableEntries_AT_Event_Wine).filter(function (i, n) { return n.Event_ID === $scope.actEvent; });
    wineList = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < wineIDofEvent.length; i++) {
        var Wine = { id: wineIDofEvent[i].Wine_ID };
        wineList.push(Wine);
    }

}

//set missing Attributes of Wine
function setAttributesOfWine() {

    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.tableEntries_wine.length; i++) {
        var wineofEvent = $($scope.tableEntries_wine).filter(function (i, n) { return n.id === wineList[i].id; });
    }

    $rootScope.WineOfEvent = wineList;
}}])
```

Everytime I want to filter `$scope.tableEntries_wine` I get an `Cannot read property 'id' of undefined` error.

I think it has something to do with my `$scope.tableEntries_wine`.
Here is how it looks like:

```
[{
    "id": "a66f426e-8466-42b6-bda5-86e39bb3b708",
    "createdAt": "2017-02-02T23:05:02.927Z",
    "updatedAt": "2017-02-02T23:06:01.763Z",
    "version": "AAAAAAAAHoU=",
    "deleted": false,
    "Name": null,
    "Wineyear": 1998,
    "Region_Description": "",
    "Qualitylevel": "",
    "Winetype_ID": "cb897aee-b32a-4802-894f-2936e9018ff5",
    "Winzer_ID": "65a71e4c-a761-42c7-9291-541e55e3784a"
},
{
    "id": "daf4557e-b6a0-4506-af25-c6b4e49c3790",
    "createdAt": "2017-02-02T23:06:59.630Z",
    "updatedAt": "2017-02-02T23:20:53.079Z",
    "version": "AAAAAAAAHpw=",
    "deleted": false,
    "Name": null,
    "Wineyear": 2012,
    "Region_Description": "",
    "Qualitylevel": "",
    "Winetype_ID": "cb897aee-b32a-4802-894f-2936e9018ff5",
    "Winzer_ID": "65a71e4c-a761-42c7-9291-541e55e3784a"
},
{
    "id": "9ab3d9c4-f2ff-4547-8a4b-883fd78a3842",
    "createdAt": "2017-02-02T23:41:08.108Z",
    "updatedAt": "2017-02-16T07:15:08.723Z",
    "version": "AAAAAAAAH1Q=",
    "deleted": false,
    "Name": null,
    "Wineyear": 1998,
    "Region_Description": "Süddings",
    "Qualitylevel": "Qualitylevel 1",
    "Winetype_ID": "cb897aee-b32a-4802-894f-2936e9018ff5",
    "Winzer_ID": "eb3c0ce8-a8d0-47dc-9a49-2261dd0513f7"
},
{
    "id": "3b920bfa-f549-474c-beca-1384503af421",
    "createdAt": "2017-02-16T07:15:12.582Z",
    "updatedAt": "2017-02-16T07:15:15.253Z",
    "version": "AAAAAAAAH1w=",
    "deleted": false,
    "Name": null,
    "Wineyear": 2001,
    "Region_Description": "",
    "Qualitylevel": "",
    "Winetype_ID": "cb897aee-b32a-4802-894f-2936e9018ff5",
    "Winzer_ID": "eb3c0ce8-a8d0-47dc-9a49-2261dd0513f7"
}]
```

When I replace `$scope.tableEntries_wine` through another table with attribute id, I don't get an error.

`wineList` looks like this:

```
[{
    "id": "a66f426e-8466-42b6-bda5-86e39bb3b708"
},
{
    "id": "9ab3d9c4-f2ff-4547-8a4b-883fd78a3842"
},
{
    "id": "3b920bfa-f549-474c-beca-1384503af421"
}]
```

Someone an idea?

Comment: Can you tel where you put console? And please send wineList

Comment: My guess would be that you need to reinitialize `wineList` and `winzerList` to an empty array again at the beginning of the `$scope.setEvent` function.

Comment: I reworked my post. Please have a look.